# Euler angle convention in TF

Tags: transform, quaternion

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm a bit confused by ROS conventions. On this page:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/geometry/CoordinateFrameConventions

It says Euler angles are specified in yaw-pitch-roll (ZYX) format in ROS. However, the `tf.transformations.quaternion_from_euler` function seems to assume roll-pitch-yaw (XYZ) format, as on this page:

http://ros.org/wiki/tf/Overview/Transformations

Doesn't this violate the convention, or am I missing something?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53688/euler-angle-convention-in-tf/) by [Jeffrey Kane Johnson](https://answers.ros.org/users/2517/jeffrey-kane-johnson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 452 on 2013-01-29

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

tf uses the Python transformation package written by Christoph Gohlke (see [http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/)). This package supports any definition of Euler angles. Simply pass the desired convention as a second parameter to `quaternion_from_euler`:

```
def quaternion_from_euler(ai, aj, ak, axes='sxyz'):
"""Return quaternion from Euler angles and axis sequence.

ai, aj, ak : Euler's roll, pitch and yaw angles
axes : One of 24 axis sequences as string or encoded tuple

>>> q = quaternion_from_euler(1, 2, 3, 'ryxz')
>>> numpy.allclose(q, [0.310622, -0.718287, 0.444435, 0.435953])
True

"""
```

And from the documentation in the header of `transformations.py`:

```
"""
A triple of Euler angles can be applied/interpreted in 24 ways, which can
be specified using a 4 character string or encoded 4-tuple:

  *Axes 4-string*: e.g. 'sxyz' or 'ryxy'

  - first character : rotations are applied to 's'tatic or 'r'otating frame
  - remaining characters : successive rotation axis 'x', 'y', or 'z'
"""
```

I suppose the tf maintainers didn't want to modify the underlying (external) python library to change the default behaviour.

So to comply with the ROS convention for Euler angles, simply use `quaternion_from_euler` like this:

```
q = tf.transformations.quaternion_from_euler(yaw, pitch, roll, 'rzyx')
```

---

Originally posted by [Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/266/stephan/) with karma: 1924 on 2013-01-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jeffrey Kane Johnson](https://answers.ros.org/users/2517/jeffrey-kane-johnson/) on 2013-01-30**:
That makes sense. Thanks.